# Different behaviours for two different submit buttons?

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to have two submit buttons in my form - one accepts meetings; the other declines them. They will both have different behaviours. How can I do is in my C# code?

The functionality I want is essentially

```
if(isPost) {
   if(//accept button pressed(Request.Form[???])) 
   {

   } 
   else 
   {


   }
}
```

Here is my HTML :

```html
<button name="accept" type="submit">Accept</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<button name="decline" type="submit">Decline</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Simple enough, but I cannot find a test for this on the Internet or in any documentation. Does anyone know what I would have for this ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler way to do this with .cshtml web pages! :)

Comment: You have tagged asp.net and razor, are you using MVC3.

Comment: I am using Web Pages with WebMatrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each button element the same name (in this example, 'SubmitButton') but a different value, then do a check for the different values in your server code, ie:

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Accept">Accept</button>
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Decline">Decline</button>
```

Then in your server code:

```
string buttonClicked = Request.Form["SubmitButton"]
if(buttonClicked == "Accept")
{
    // Accept code
}
else if(buttonClicked == "Decline")
{
    // Decline code
}
```

Be aware that this won't work on some earlier versions of IE though, and you may have to do a little javascript on the client prior to the post request being made.

Comment: This is the easiest solution here and exactly the simple functionality I wanted, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you have a controller action looking like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string accept, string decline)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accept))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else 
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using MVC3 you would do something like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Accept","Meeting")) 
{
   <input type="submit" value="Accept" /> 
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Decline","Meeting")) 
{
   <input type="submit" value="Decline" /> 
}
```

You would then just have your accept and decline code in your Accept and Decline actions of your meeting controller respectively.  No need for an if statement at all.

Example controller

```
public class MeetingController : Controller
    {   
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Accept()
        {
            //Do accept stuff
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Decline()
        {
            //Do decline stuff
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in the codebehind in c# you'd be looking for which button was clicked. You'd have an event handler for each button, and you code would react according to which button was clicked.

```
this.btnRejectAppointment.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRejectAppointment_Click);
```

And then your method

```
private void btnRejectAppointment_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //code to reject appt.
}
```

And you'd have the SAME set for the other button.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions - use two buttons of type `LinkButton` but specify slightly different `PostBackUrl`:

```xml
<!-- Accept meeting button -->
<asp:LinkButton ID="acceptMeeting" runat="server"
                PostBackUrl="MeetingsManager.aspx?Mode=Accept" />

<!-- Decline meeting button -->    
<asp:LinkButton ID="declineMeeting" runat="server"
                PostBackUrl="MeetingsManager.aspx?Mode=Decline" />
```

And in code behind:

```cs
public enum Mode
{
  Unknown,
  Accept,
  Decline
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Mode currentMode = Mode.Unknown;
    var rawMode = Request.QueryString["Mode"];
    if (rawMode != null)
    {
       currentMode = (Mode)Enum.Parse(
                                 typeof(Mode), 
                                 rawMode.ToString())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a very clean way to do this. As people can mess with the querystring, having two buttons on the page, each with it's own linked event handler and method for processing is a better approach.

Comment: You can seperate processing by the methods anyway

Comment: s'pose this applies to asp.net mvc rather than the webforms model

Comment: @coalvilledave : may be, why you think so?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've used webforms, forgot about all the event stuff tbh.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Button control has OnClick event, so add different handler to every your button:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="MyHandler1" ... />
```

in code behind:

```
protected void MyHandler1(object sender, EventArgs args)
{ /* do stuff */ }
```